# Creating real-time applications with handler.postDelayed (Android)?

Tags: php, android, performance, android-studio

Is it okay to use handler.postDelayed for getting real time data from the server? Say I need to build a chat application. I need to notify users of incoming messages. So in this case, can i create a postDelayed which runs a function that tells volley or retrofit or any other rest api to send a request to the PHP file, to check if there are any new messages to the current user, every 1 second? Is this a clean way? Are there any limitations? What could be the consequences? Are there any other ways which is more efficient? Hope you will answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

While this might work in some cases, it will be a bad approach. Rather you can use one of the following suggestion:

1. Use a socket service and keep the connection alive as long as you want. You can use multiple approaches to keep the connection alive.
2. Use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to do the periodic task. Using WorkManager can ensure that your task is executed definitely.